# "invalid arithmetic operator" in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

cat test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
key="index";
arr[$key]="val"
echo ${arr[${key}]}
```

/bin/bash-x test.sh

```
+ key=index
+ arr[$key]=val
+ echo val
val
```

then I modify the test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
key="index.index";
arr[$key]="val"
echo ${arr[${key}]}
```

/bin/bash -x test.sh

```
+ key=index.index
+ arr[$key]=val
test.sh: line 3: index.index: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".index")
test.sh: line 4: index.index: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".index")
```

why this error appears, any suggestion will be appreciate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare the array variable as an associative array with `declare -A arr`.

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
set -x 
declare -A arr
key="index.index";
arr["$key"]="val"
echo "${arr["${key}"]}"

$ ./test.sh 
+ declare -A arr
+ key=index.index
+ arr["$key"]=val
+ echo val
val
```

Comment: It's worth noting that before, the string "index" was being treated as an unset variable when used as an index, and so evaluated to 0.

Answer (score 7):

This:

```
key="index";
arr[$key]="val"
echo ${arr[${key}]}
```

only *appears* to work. Since `arr` is an ordinary array, not an associative array, it can only be indexed by non-negative integer values.

Consider this valid code:

```
index=42
key="index"
arr[$key]="val"
echo ${arr[42]}
echo ${arr[index]}
echo ${arr[$index]}
echo ${arr['index']}
echo ${arr["index"]}
echo ${arr[\index]}
```

All the `echo` statements print `val`. Since the index is treated as an arithmetic expression, it can refer to a variable (in this case, `$index`) either with or without the `$` prefix -- even if it's a quoted string.

In your code, where you never assigned a value to `$index`, `${arr[${key}]}` expands to `${arr[index]}`, which is equivalent to `${arr[$index]}`, which is treated (by default) as equivalent to `${arr[0]}`.

(If you have `set -o nounset`, then references to unset variables are treated as errors, and your code will produce an error message.)

Your second chunk of code:

```
key="index.index";
arr[$key]="val"
echo ${arr[${key}]}
```

is invalid because `index.index` is not a valid variable name -- even though you probably meant it to be just a string used as an array index.

If you want `arr` to permit arbitrary strings as indices, it needs to be an *associative array*. You can create a non-associative array simply by assigning to it (or by using `declare -a`), but an associative array can only be created with `declare -A`.

Associative arrays were added to bash in version 4. If you're using an earlier version of bash, `declare -A` is not supported. You'll need to upgrade to a newer bash, code up some clumsy alternative, or use a language that does support associative arrays, like Awk, Python, or Perl.

Adding `declare -A arr` (as [user000001's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18250958/827263) suggests) should solve the problem (if you have bash 4), but it's instructive to understand what your original code is actually doing (or rather not doing).

(BTW, thanks for asking this; I learned a lot as I was composing this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

This behavior varies by BASH version. Older BASH versions only allowed non negative integers as the keys in arrays.

Please note that `dot/period` is not allowed in a variable name in BASH.

See this Q&A for more details about allowed characters in BASH: [Allowed characters in linux environment variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names)

**EDIT:**

(Many thanks to @chepner for this addendum)

Regular arrays (not associative array) are indexed by integer only. Any expression used as an index between square brackets is treated as an arithmetic expression. $key expands to index, which is then treated as an (unset) variable which expands to 0. If you assigned a value of, say, 3 to index, then `${array[$key]} -> ${array[index]} -> ${array[3]}`. It's a type of implicit indirect parameter expansion

Comment: Does this also apply for associative arrays? Because it seems to work when you `declare -A` the array.

Comment: It didn't work for me in `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`. Which BASH version do you have?

Comment: I have `GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`. Strange

Comment: Regular arrays (not associative array) are indexed by integer only. Any expression used as an index between square brackets is treated as an arithmetic expression. `$key` expands to `index`, which is then treated as an (unset) variable which expands to 0. If you assigned a value of, say, 3 to `index`, then `${array[$key]} -> ${array[index]} -> ${array[3]}`. It's a type of implicit indirect parameter expansion.

Comment: Your first paragraph is incorrect. For an ordinary array, indices can only be numbers. For an associative array (which can only be created with `declare -A`), indices can be any arbitrary strings. `declare -A assoc ; assoc[foo.bar]=42 ; echo ${assoc[foo.bar]}` prints `42`

Comment: @KeithThompson: What you're saying is correct for newer BASH versions. On my BASH version (4.1.2) even `declare -A` didn't work as explained in chepner's comment.

Comment: You're right; associative arrays were added to bash in version 4. But there's still nothing special about the `.` character in the key/index of an array. Variable names must be identifiers, which means they can't contain `.`. Indices for ordinary arrays must be non-negative integers; there's nothing special about `.`, they can't contain any punctuation other than `_`. Indices for associative arrays (which exist only in bash 4 and higher) can be any arbitrary string; again, there's nothing special about `.`.

Comment: Adding correct information after incorrect information, but leaving the incorrect information there, is hardly a way to correct a bad answer.