# Function name valid in bash but not in sh

Tags: bash, shell, sh

While playing around with bash and sh, I found out that the following is valid in bash:

```
system.out.println () { printf "$1"; }
```

but not in sh:

```
sh: `system.out.println': not a valid identifier
```

Why would this difference be there? Does the function defined above violate some convention (POSIX etc.) that causes this error?

Comment: While I'm not sure this will solve your problem, you could try using aliases. Like this:

ldot_function () {

  ls -A $* | egrep '^\.'

}

alias l.=ldot_function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's just the dots, you can't use dots in shell function names. Or any variable name, for that matter.

I'll link you to this question: [Allowed characters in linux environment variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names)

Comment: In the POSIX shell, a function [name](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_231) must consist solely of underscores and alphanumeric characters.