# Read properties file from shell script

Tags: shell, properties-file

I am reading a properties file having different paths like

```
path=/home/xxx/yyy

path=/home/zzz
```

from a shell script. I am using

```
. /home/test.properties
```

To read and $path to print to get path into a variable. But as obvious it is overwriting the path variable. Can someone suggest a better way to get these paths into variables in script. Thanks.

EDIT: I am using bash.

Comment: Are you talking about the special variable `$PATH`? Are you trying to join all of the paths together?

Comment: No, as I am using path in properties file so I am using $path to get it. Ultimately I want to search for some text in all paths provided by properties file.

Comment: Which shell are you using? Some shells (e.g. bash and ksh) support arrays, which would be useful in this case.

Comment: @TomFenech  I have edited the description. Using bash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21591956/1028589 should suit your needs