# Which characters are allowed in a bash alias

Tags: linux, macos, bash

I recently added

```
alias ..='cd ..'
alias ...='cd ../..'
alias ....='cd ../../..'
```

to my bash_aliases file. Playing around with this, I noticed that while aliasing `..` was allowed, aliasing `.` was not. What other punctuation characters are allowed in bash aliases?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? I can alias `.` just fine. However, `.` is already defined as a command name in the POSIX specification, so you probably should not shadow it with an alias.

Answer (score 10):

Bash aliases definitely can't contain these characters: space  , tab `\t`, newline `\n`, `/`, `\`, `$`, `` ` ``, `=`, `|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `'` and `"`.

The Bash Reference Manual [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html):

> The characters `/`, `$`, `` ` ``, `=` and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name.

"Shell metacharacters" are [defined](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Definitions.html) as

> A character that, when unquoted, separates words. A metacharacter is a `space`, `tab`, `newline`, or one of the following characters: `|`, `&`, `;`, `(`, `)`, `<`, or `>`.

"Quoting characters" aren't [explicitly listed](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) but they are the backslash `\` and the single `'` and double `"` quotes.

Bash checks alias names [in `legal_alias_name()`](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/general.c#L423-L424) which is implemented here: [1](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/syntax.h#L72), [2](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/syntax.h#L74), [3](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/ec8113b9861375e4e17b3307372569d429dec814/syntax.h#L83-L87). Looking through the output of [mksyntax.c](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/mksyntax.c) (a C program that generates another C program) on my system, `shellbreak()` will return true for these 10 characters: `\t\n &();<>|`, `shellxquote()` for these 4: `` "'\` ``, and `shellexp()` for `$`, finally `legal_alias_name()` also checks for `/`.

However, there are other limitations from 1) how Bash tokenizes the `alias` expression that you would have to write to define the alias and 2) how it will tokenize a command that starts with your alias. Namely, for 1), `=` can't appear in an alias name, probably because `alias foo=bar=baz` would be parsed as `foo` = `bar=baz`, not `foo=bar` = `baz`. For 2), from my experiments, you can define an alias with `!`, the [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html) character, but if you try to use it, you'll get a `command not found` error, unless the `!` is at the end of the command. There's probably other characters, the safest bet is to stick to numbers, letters and the underscore.

Comment: For completeness: I use `!` in many of my "dangerous" commands (like force push `gpf!` or interactive rebase `gri!`), but only as the final character. Not sure if they work in other locations in the alias name. Came to this thread looking to see how else I might use `!` :)

Comment: @Xunnamius `alias "abc!"=echo` works but `alias "a!bc"=echo` and `alias "a\!bc"=echo` and `alias "!abc"=echo` don't.

Answer (score 9):

It's always been safer to use functions instead:

```
function .. { cd '..'; }
function ... { cd '../..'; }
function .... { cd '../../..'; }
```

Or for a conservative preference:

```
..() { cd '..'; }
...() { cd '../..'; }
....() { cd '../../..'; }
```

> What is safer about doing it this way?

Aliases affect first-class syntax (if, case, etc.) and its commands are specified using quotes. It's like having to use eval unnecessarily. Using functions on the other is straightforward and you know exactly how the arguments are expanded. TL;DR aliases are a hack. It's like using a #define statement in C when you can simply define a function. It's something beginners would love to compose.

If anyone would want to define default arguments to a command, you can use command to make the function call the external command to avoid recursion. That's the right way to do it. E.g. `function grep { command grep --color=auto "$@"; }`

Comment: what is safer about doing it this way?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names) environment variables names can only contain

> uppercase letters, digits, and the '_' (underscore) from the
> characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a
> digit. Other characters may be permitted by an implementation;
> applications shall tolerate the presence of such names.

But variables are not really the same the same of alias names.

In practice a `-`(dash) should be added to the list because it is a defacto standard in debian(`apt-get`).  In addition `_~@#%^.,` all work and `` ><'"|=()`/?[]+! ``. don't.  In addition you have to worry about `$PATH` and characters like `:`.  It appears space and linebreaks could work if they are properly escaped or quoted like so `"a b"`.

Comment: I tried to use a `/` in my alias name but it didn't work.

Comment: The GNU [manual for bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html) says "The characters `/`, `$`, `\``, `=` and any of the shell metacharacters or quoting characters listed above may not appear in an alias name." so this answer (which says `/` and `$` are okay) is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html
I wouldn't name an alias .. in linux . is a special name for the current director and .. is for the parent directory. there could be some obscure process that could be screwed up by aliasing .. for cd

Comment: `..` is just a (special) directory name, so syntactically it's no different than something like `foobar`.

Comment: im aware, and normally it wouldnt matter, but if you put it in bashrc, and some system tries to execute it and instead cd's to it, then it will be weird, which is why as konsolebox said, functions are safer

Comment: The problems you describe are the same whether you define `..` as an alias or a function, but neither would be invoked if `..` were used as the argument to a command. Since `.bashrc` is only invoked for interactive shells, there's no worry that you will change the behavior of any shell script, especially system scripts (as long as you don't mess with `/etc/bashrc`, since they scripts will run as `root`, not a user account).

Comment: ah ok i see what you mean