# declare not a valid identifier bash

Tags: bash, variables, for-loop, sed, declare

I have a problem with my a bash script. What I do is assign variables like this.

```
   for ((i=START;i<=END;i++)
declare var$i=$(something)
done
```

And it works, but now I have a problem with finnish characters like  å, ä, ö. What declare says is something like this

```
bash:declare 'wörd' not a valid identifier
```

Though it works fine if I do it like this

```
declare var2=$(sömething)
```

I can convert the characters with sed but it's better to have them like always, so this is a last resort solution.
So I would like to know how can I assign variables like

```
var$i
```

with the finnish characters.
The wörd word is part of the output of my command 'something'. When there are two words or more only the word(s) that contain the character ö , ä and so on are not assigned to the variable, so if the output of the command was "something wörd" then the only thing that is being shown with echo is something.

Comment: How do Finnish characters show up in `$i`, and why do you want to do this?

Comment: I assign the output of some commands to var1,var2 and then do calculations. Sorry I don't knwo what you mean on the first part.

Comment: Where does `wörd` come in?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821201/3776858

Comment: The wörd comes is part of the output of the command is assign the variable to. Something like this: declare var$i=$(something) so the wörd is the output of the command something.

Comment: `bash` identifiers are ASCII only (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _). A bare `wörd=1` (without `declare`) is interpreted as a command, not an assignment statement, due to the non-ASCII character. It *could* deviate from the POSIX spec, as described in the link provided by Cyrus, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bash` simply does not allow identifiers using characters other than A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and _. However, the error you describe is just a side effect of that limitation. `declare` is a command which takes a string argument that *looks* like an assignment statement, but the semantics are slightly different. Consider this command:

```
foo () {
    echo "something wörd"
}
```

In an assignment statement, the right-hand side does not undergo word splitting, so you don't have to quote the command substitution. The following works fine:

```
$ word3=$(foo)
$ echo "$word"
something wörd
```

With `declare`, however, the command substitution *does* undergo word splitting, so when you write

```
$ i=3
$ declare word$i=$(foo)
```

it's equivalent to the command

```
$ declare word3=something wörd
```

which passes *two* names for `declare` to create, `word3` (which gets a value) and `wörd` (which is an invalid name). `declare word3="something wörd"` would work fine; the shell's word-splitting is already done by the time `declare` gets the argument.

With `declare`, then, you need to quote the command substitution (or the entire string) in order for the entire output to be treated as the value for the new variable.

```
$ i=3
$ declare "word$i=$(foo)"
$ echo "$word3"
something wörd
```

Comment: The claim about bash identifiers being restricted to `[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*` is not true. Bash allows an identifier to start with any single-byte character which `isalpha` in the current locale, and to continue with any character is `isalnum`. If the locale were iso-8859-1, then scandinavian, french, portuguese and spanish alphabetic letters would work just fine. However, it won't work with UTF-8 locales because the non-us-ascii alphabetic characters are multibyte.

Comment: Thanks. I knew as I was typing that part of the answer it sounded unnecessarily strict, but I did t think to test it with a non-English locale.

Comment: It's not easy to test, either, since most systems these days use UTF-8 console I/O, even if the locale is changed. So you have to create an ISO-8859-1 file as well as setting the locale. But it does work, honest. (And Posix requires it to work, too.)

Comment: To actually take what @rici said one further, the bash identifier issue is a situation that can arise when you utilise shell opts, particularly `set -o posix`.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your script using `/bin/bash` in command line instead if `sh` (:

Instead of :

```
>> sh script.sh
```

Try :

```
>> /bin/bash script.sh
```