# How to trigger downstream jenkins job with File parameter as parameter?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins Job which accepts a File as a parameter and using same file I would like to trigger downstream project.  How do I do it ? It seems jenkins doesn't support passing files as parameter to downstream project. I am using  'Trigger/Call builds on other projects' to trigger a downstream project.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) but be aware of the following:

The *File Parameter* help reads:

> *The name of the submitted file is available in the environment variable whose name is the same as file location. For example, if you set the file location to be <s>abc.zip</s>* [UPLOADED_FILE], *then <s>${abc.zip}</s>* [${UPLOADED_FILE}] *would give you the original file name passed from the browser (such as my.zip.) <s>The name will not include the directory name portion.</s>*

[Strikethroughs and additions by me.]

[image] **Unfortunately this is wrong in more than one respect (with Jenkins v1.609.1):**

- The file name *abc.zip* becoming an environment variable name is bad.
- If there is a directory name portion in the *File Location* field it **is** included in the variable's name.

**Why is each of these bad?**

Well, the latter is the opposite to the inline help and both might lead to unexpected results (and it did in my case), since '.' and '/' are not standardized characters in variable names according to [IEEE Std 1003.1, 2013 Edition:](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

> *Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the  ( '_' )* [...]

See also [Robert Gamble's answer to *Allowed characters in linux environment variable names*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821183/1744774).

So, the answer is:

- Don't use a path or an extension in *File Parameter* → *File Location*, use e.g. just *UPLOADED_FILE*
- <Your upstream project> → *Configure* → *Add post-build action* → *Trigger parameterized build on other projects* 
  → *Add parameters* → *Predefined parameters* → *Parameters*:

  > *KEY=value pairs, one per line (Java properties file format). [...]*
  >
  > *Current build parameters and/or environment variables can be used in form: ${PARAM} or $PARAM.*

  Long story short. This passes the file's absolute name to your downstream project:

  ```
  ENV_VAR_IN_DOWNSTREAM_PROJECT=${WORKSPACE}/${UPLOADED_FILE}
  ```

**UPDATE**

I created a respective issue: [*[JENKINS-28996] Environment variable name created from File Parameter → File Location contains the "directory name portion" though stated differently in its inline help*](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28996)

Comment: this doesnt allow files as parameters.

Comment: @MichaelNiemand How is Jenkins supposed to pass _files_ as in _container with content?_ It's not a file manager, after all. ;-) _File names_ on the other hand aren't a big deal. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @GeroldBroser so it is not possible to pass a file parameter from a job A run on jenkins master to a downstream job B run on a slave?

Comment: @thunderbird As I said: You can pass a _file name_ as parameter. You can't pass _a file with its content_ as parameter, of course. You can use a combination of a file name parameter and the [Copy To Slave Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+To+Slave+Plugin) in your case.

Comment: thanks.. i was also looking into copy to save and the download file from url plugins.

Comment: You can use the parameter factory *For every matching file, invoke one build* from the Parameterized Trigger Plugin. It pushes a specified file into the  workspace of your downstream job. Check my response [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36157620/3623345)

Answer (score 0):

This approach assumes you have the file in the current job's workspace.

```
pipeline
{
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Pass file type param to build job') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def propertiesFilePath = "${env.WORKSPACE}/sample.properties"
                    build job: 'other-project',
                            parameters: [[$class: "FileParameterValue", name: "propertiesFile", file: new FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl(new File(propertiesFilePath))]]

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the name of the downstream/child job is 'other-project' and the name of the file type parameter in this downstream/child job is 'propertiesFile'. The type [FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/FileParameterValue.FileItemImpl.html) is defined in the class [FileParameterValue](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/master/core/src/main/java/hudson/model/FileParameterValue.java) and is internally used in jenkins to handle FileItem, also adding serialization support to the same.

Comment: I get `NoSuchFileException: foo/bar/blah/myfile.rpm` in the downstream job. If the file is serialized, I would expect it to work regardless of on which worker it runs. Any idea?