# pass a file parameter to a downstream job

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-cli

I am trying to trigger a build on a job from another job. The job to be triggered requires a file parameter. I am using parameterized trigger plugin to trigger the job but unfortunately have no clue how to pass the the file parameter. The plugin [page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) also has no clear information as to how to do it. There are a few similar question asked here but none of them were correctly answered.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger downstream jenkins job with File parameter as parameter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30666529/how-to-trigger-downstream-jenkins-job-with-file-parameter-as-parameter)

Comment: @GeroldBroser the answer doesn't really solve the problem of sending a file as a parameter....but i do have an answer now...have to try it first and will add it here if it works

Comment: _Possible duplicate of <question>_ does not say anything about whether there is an answer that solves a problem or whether there is an answer at all. It means that this question is a possible duplicate of the one linked to. See [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)