# How to pass file to downstream job which blocks upstream job?

Tags: java, git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

What I want to accomplish is to checkout code from `develop` branch, merge it to `master` branch, build `app.war`, run tests and if tests succeed push to `master` branch.

Tests should be run in separate job which needs `app.war`.

My current setup is as follows:

1. Job `Main` checks out from `develop`, merges it to `master`and builds `app.war`
2. Job `Main` triggers job `Test` in *Post build step* (`Test` needs `app.war` previously built)
3. If `Test` succeeds, `Main` pushes to `master` branch in *Post build action*

I tried to use *Copy Artifact Plugin* but the problem is that with it, I can only archive artifact in *Post build action* while I am triggering `Test` in *Post build step*.

How to pass `app.war` to `Test` job? Is it possible to do with *Copy Artifact Plugin*?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### 1. Copying artifacts

You can put a wrapper job around it and have the Build job and the Test job called as build step by using *Trigger/call builds on other projects*. Since the build is encapsuled in its own job now, you can archive its artifacts and copy them over to the `Test` job.

### 2. Share workspace

Another way would be to just share a workspace between build and test.

### 3. Pass file as parameter

A neat way to pass a file to a downstream job is, to pass it as parameter with the help of the [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin).

You push a file into your downstream job's workspace simply by selecting the parameter factory *For every matching file, invoke one build* in a build step *Trigger/call builds on other projects*. 
There you specify the target file (wildcards allowed) and the name it should get in the child workspace.

[image]

Note: <s>Your downstream job does *not* need to have the option *This build is parameterized* set, the file will be copied either way.</s> Edit: This might not work anymore, see comments.

Comment: 1) Did you mean that I should create another job `Build` which will check out from `develop`, merge to `master` and build `app.war`. After that `Test` will use that `app.war` and if it succeeds, `Main` will push to `master`? In this scenario, `Main` and `Build` should check out from `develop` in different periods of time and there is possibility that they will not get the same codebase (though, highly unlikely).

2) Regarding sharing workspace, could you point me to some resource for this setup? Thanks!

Comment: If you want to use the artifact copy method for your `Test` job i would use `Main` to check out `develop` and share the workspace with `Build`, there you can archive the artifact that will be used by `Test`, lastly `Main` can push the merged branch to `master`. However, you could also just share the workspace of `Main` with `Build` *and*  `Test`, really depends on the use case and what your requirements are. When sharing workspaces you also need to be careful to have all jobs run on the same machine as the wrapper job (`Main`in this case)

Comment: I found another neat way to pass a file to a downstream job. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thank you. The idea of wrapper job was very helpful. I did as stated in my upper comment, part 1). Problem with checking out in different periods of time I solved by passing ${GIT_COMMIT} env. variable to `Build` job.

Comment: Important caveat about Copy Artifact plugin; it wouldn't let me use it since my upstream build that triggered it was still, at least that's what the errors seemed to indicate. I've got upstream jobs that trigger downstream jobs and then finish certain operations once those complete depending on what was required. It's a bit over-engineered but it allows a ton flexibility... so long as Jenkins plays nice ;)

Comment: You should be able to archive the artifact in the 1st child job, and copy it in the 2nd child job. You can *not* archive an artifact in the parent job and copy it to a child job launched from said parent, as you can only archive in the post-build step.

Comment: how do you "Pass file as parameter" in pipeline ? I can't find the option when I try to find the right Pipeline Syntax.

Comment: _Note: Your downstream job does not need to have the option This build is parameterized set, the file will be copied either way._ This is **NOT** true and may result in server logs, such as _Skipped parameter `app.war` as it is undefined on `Example - downstream project`._ You HAVE to define the parameter, unless you are using unsecure settings. Exactly what happened (the logs) on my setup: Jenkins 2.73.2, Parametrized Trigger 2.35.2 with Tomcat 8.5.4.

Comment: @predi Can you explain what you mean by "server logs"?   I'm on Jenkins 2.9.0 and the latest Parameterized Trigger plugin. I have setup the parameter factory __For every matching file, invoke one build__ as suggested here, and (as you mention) the needed "This project is parameterised" __file parameter__ in the downstream job. However, my files never shows up in the downstream job, and there's no info to find in either of the console logs. Any advice on how you made it work?

Comment: @fsteff, there was no indication of why it was not working in the consoles for me either, so I checked Tomcat logs out of habit, `$TOMCAT_HOME/logs/catalina.YYYY-MM-DD.log` to be precise. You should check your server logs for error messages.

Comment: Turned out that it was a misunderstanding on my side - but very much influence of the text in the plugin :-( . When triggering the job with **For every matching file, invoke one build**, the field "File Name In Child Projects" actually means "_**Name of file parameter in child job**_". Also, if that name is **InputFile**, then when your file shows up in the child project, it will actually be named **InputFile**. Anonymous file copying (as original answer suggested) seems not to be possible.

Comment: Seems some things have changes, i added this info in OP.