# Changing slaves in jenkins-workflow

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I am configuring a Jenkins-workflow and requirement is to use Linux(server1) for compilation part of workflow and than windows (server2)for testing because testing tool is not compatible with Linux , After testing is complete need to switch back to same Linux(server1) to continue rest of workflow.
How to switch slaves in same workflow if not possible, what are other ways to achieve this.
Appreciate suggestions !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by jenkins-workflow you mean [Jenkins Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) then you can do it like this:

```
node('server1') {
    //some compilation steps
    node('server1') {
        // more compilation steps
    }
    //continue workflow for server1
}
```

You can send any files between the nodes using `stash`/`unstash` steps.

Comment: Works but better to not nest `node` blocks, lest you consume an executor slot while the computer is actually idle waiting for another agent.

Comment: Exactly, because executor here serves as a lock for the workspace of this particular build. Sometimes this is a cheap alternative for stashing gigs of workspace files or manually managing workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use a wrapper job which starts compilation and test jobs with *Trigger/call builds on other projects*.

That way you can move the artifacts with help of *Archive the artifacts* option (which you would use ine the compilation post-build action) and the [Copy Artifacts Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) (which you'd use in test build step).

You can define on which machine/label your jobs run easily either static via default configuration in your job, or dynamically with help of [NodeLabel Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin)

### Note

You can also try option 3 mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36157080/how-to-pass-file-to-downstream-job-which-blocks-upstream-job/36157620#36157620), however im not sure if it works when files have to be moved in between different machines.

Might be worth to check out though, as if it works, that could be alot more convenient.