# source a file containing environment variables including "dash" character in bash?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I'm using bash and have a file called `x.config` that contains the following:

```
MY_VAR=Something1
ANOTHER=Something2
```

To load these as environment variables I just use source:

```
$ source x.config
```

But this doesn't work if `MY_VAR` is called `MY-VAR`:

```
MY-VAR=Something1
ANOTHER=Something2
```

If I do the same thing I get:

```
x.config:1: command not found: MY-VAR=Something1
```

I've tried escaping `-` and a lot of other things but I'm stuck. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: Variable names cannot contain hyphen

Comment: Why can't you use underscore ?

Comment: Well I know you can escape it if you do env 'MY-VAR=..' so I suppose there must be a workaround?

Comment: @123 Because I need to pass it into an application that requires "-"

Comment: @Johan What? You don't/can't pass the variable name to other applications...

Comment: @Johan `Well I know you can escape it if you do env 'MY-VAR=..' ` No you can't

Comment: @123 Sorry, what I mean is that the application reads its config from the environment (i.e. the defined environment variables) and it requires hyphen in some of the configuration names. This works for example when using when I use docker or docker-compose to read a set of predefined environment variables from a file.

Comment: @Johan You can't do it, change your application to use valid env variables.

Comment: hm. I can set a variable containing a dash from python...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names

Comment: @123 I take your word for it. It would be interesting to know you docker-compose manage to do this though? But that's another question I suppose.

Comment: @123 `env 'MY-VAR=3' bash` will add the variable to the environment; it's just not exposed as a shell environment variable. It will be passed to any child processes which may be able to use it.

Comment: @chepner So it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure `bash` workaround that might work for you is to re-run the script using `env` to set the environment. Add this to the beginning of your script.

```
if [[ ! -v myscript_env_set ]]; then
    export myscript_env_set=1
    readarray -t newenv < x.config
    exec env "${newenv[@]}" "$0" "$@"
fi

# rest of the script here
```

This assumes that `x.config` doesn't contain anything except variable assignments. If `myscript_env_set` is not in the current environment, put it there so that the next invocation skips this block. Then read the assignments into an array to pass to `env`. Using `exec` replaces the current process with another invocation of the script, but with the desired variables in the environment.

Answer (score 1):

A dash (`-`) in an [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names) is not portable, and as you noticed, will cause a lot of problems. You can't set these from bash. *Fix the application you want to invoke*.

That being said, if you can't change the target app, you can do this from python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

with open('x.config') as f:
    for line in f:
        name, value = line.strip().split('=')
        os.environ[name] = value

os.system('/path/to/your/app')
```

This is a very simplistic config reader, and for a more complex syntax you might want to use `ConfigParser`.