# Setting a Envirionment Variable in OS X which has equals sign in value

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I am trying to set a environment variable in OS X which has a equals sign in the value but when I echo that variable I don't get anything. Without the equals sign it is fine. How do I set a equals sign as the value?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2821183/2836621

Comment: That talks about the name not the value

Comment: Please show us what you're actually trying to set.

Comment: for example export test='hello there = hello'

Comment: This works fine for me in bash. Please provide a full example of the problem including the commands you entered and the output.

Comment: export test='hello=123'
echo $test is giving an empty line.
export test='hello123'
echo $test gives hello123

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
export fred="abc=123"
echo "$fred"
abc=123
```

Comment: Yes that is whant im trying to set