# Perl script does not recognize paths which contains environment variables

Tags: perl, environment-variables

I got a file with a path on each line. I insert those lines into an array `@dirs`. Some of the paths include environment variables. An example of a valid file with paths:

```
/some/valid/path
$HOME/dir
$SOME_ENV/dir
```

Each path, I would like to check if it contains a file called `abc`. So I use:

```
foreach my $dir (@dirs) {
   chmod($dir);
   my $file = $dir."/"."abc";
   print "invalid dir: $dir" unless((-e $file) && (-s $file));
}
```

But, for some reason, it does not recognize the environment variables, meaning it fails even though `$SOME_ENV/dir` contains the `abc` file.

Also, the script does recognize those environment variables, if I use it as following:

```
print $ENV{SOME_ENV}."\n";
print $ENV{HOME}."\n";
```

Furthermore, I tried to use the `abs_path` of the `Cwd` module, in order to get the real path of the path (so it won't include the environment variable), but it also, does not recognize the environment variable.

why `(-e $file)` does not recognize the environment variable? How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: And if they aren't known ahead of time: `no strict 'vars';use Env;`

Comment: What is that call to `chmod` for? The first parameter should be the new permissions

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I don't know the paths. user gives a file and I extract the paths from it, into an array. And even though this path to a dir contains `abc`, the check `(-e $file)` will return false, because it just (for some reason) copies the string without using the env.

Comment: Did you mean to use `chomp` ([perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)) instead of `chmod`?

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing in your code evaluating `$dir` for environment variables inside of it, so you'd need to add that. A very simplistic way could be done like this - using a regular expression to find the variables and then replacing them with their values in the `%ENV` hash.

```
$dir =~ s/\$([A-Z0-9_]*)/$ENV{$1}/g;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This regex won't work for `$SOME_ENV` (only for a string with `A-Z` letters). Also, will it work, if the env is located in the middle/end of the string?

Comment: You can simply add _ inside the character class so it becomes `[A-Z_]`. The regex is not anchored so it will work anywhere in the string.

Comment: @Grinnz sure but what if user has numbers or any other symbol which is not in the `[A-Z]` range?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 `[A-Z0-9_]` will cover digits as well. See [perlrecharclass](https://perldoc.pl/perlrecharclass#Bracketed-Character-Classes) for more on how character classes work.

Comment: Also the /e modifier is not necessary, since `$ENV{$1}` will interpolate fine on its own.

Comment: I think that `$dir =~ s/\$(\S+?)(\/|$)/$ENV{$1}$2/g;` is a better solution. it will handle any symbol until the first `/` or the end of the line. What do you think?

Comment: @TTaJTa4 `s/\$([^\s/]+)/$ENV{$1}/g` is a simpler way to achieve that without backtracking. Read as many non-space non-slash characters as follow the `$`.

Comment: See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names, if you're curious why [A-Z0-9_] should be sufficient as a character class vs more permissive negated character classes.