# Issue with reading CF environment variables in application.properties file

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, cloud-foundry, concourse

I am having difficult in deploying a spring-webmvc application to cloud foundry. Error is related to application.properties placeholders are not resolved by CF environment. Error is below

```
22:14:41.152: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner               INFO    At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
22:14:41.215: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
22:14:41.544: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] lina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/] INFO    Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
22:14:41.947: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] org.cloudfoundry.reconfiguration.ProfileUtils      INFO    'cloud' profile activated
22:14:42.088: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] n.CloudPropertySourceApplicationContextInitializer INFO    'cloud' property source added
22:14:42.090: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] [CONTAINER] erviceReconfigurationApplicationContextInitializer INFO    Reconfiguration enabled
22:14:42.633: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] 03:14:42.622 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
22:14:42.639: [APP/PROC/WEB.0]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
22:14:42.633: [APP/PROC/WEB.0] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/test-servlet.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.url' in string value "${datasource.url}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'datasource.url' in string value "${datasource.url}"
22:14:42.633: [APP/PROC/WEB.0]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:211) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
```

I am deploying application using concourse to CF. below is my pipeline code:

```
jobs:
- name: maven-build-and-deploy
  serial: true
  public: true
  plan: 
  - get: mygit
  - task: mvn-package
    privileged: true
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: test/alpine-jdk8-maven
          tag: latest
      inputs:
      - name: test11
      outputs:
      - name: maven-package-output
      run:
        path: sh
        args:
        -  -exc
        -   |
              set -xe
              cd test
              mvn package
              cp target/test.war ../maven-package-output
  - put: cf-push
    resource: cf-env
    params:
      path: maven-package-output/test.war
      manifest: test/manifest.yml
      environment_variables:
        datasource.url: ((datasource.url))
        datasource.username: ((datasource.username))
        datasource.password: ((datasource.password))
```

Above environment variables are configured in Cloud Foundry.
These environment variables are read by application.properties file and this is causing issue.

I have configured the same application in local tomcat. created a setenv.sh file with properties and copied to tomcat/bin folder. when deployed working succcessfully.

When deployed to CF, causing issue.

Below is my pom.xml, including only depenedencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.jpa.data.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
database.url = ${datasource.url}
database.username = ${datasource.username}
database.password = ${datasource.password}
```

test-servlet.xml (context loader)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx  http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" />
    

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
  </bean>
```

How will application.properties read environment variables from CF environment.
Please help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Anyone please let me know how to proceed on this issue?

Comment: After enabling auto re-configuration, I could get data source connection. But still I want to read user-defined properties. I tried reading them using VCAP. still not reading

Answer (score 0):

In your pipeline, you are setting these env variables:

```
        datasource.url: ((datasource.url))
        datasource.username: ((datasource.username))
        datasource.password: ((datasource.password))
```

A problem I see, there may be others, is that `datasource.url` is the actual env variable name that will be used, however, that's not technically a valid env variable name. The `.` is not allowed (neither is a `-`). These variables will end up not being set because the shell will filter them out, due to the invalid characters.

[Allowed characters in Linux environment variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names)

The recommendation from the Spring Boot documentation is to name environment variables:

1. In all CAPS
2. Change spaces and `.` (dot or period) to `_` (underscore)
3. Remove `-`.

So if you want to set the `datasource.url` property, you need to set `DATASOURCE_URL`. Similary, if you want to set the property `foo.bar-prop`, you'd want to set an env variable of `FOO_BARPROP`.

See the docs on relaxed bindings for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding