# Can we use an env variable named _MY_SECRET?

Tags: node.js, environment-variables, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use an environment variable in my serverMiddleware in Nuxt.js. It works fine when it starts with a letter (`MY_SECRET`) but since it's a private server variable I'd like it to start with an underscore (`_MY_SECRET`). However for some reason the latter is undefined.

This is my basic setup:

```
// .env

MY_SECRET = hello
_MY_SECRET = world
```

```js
// serverMiddleware/index.js

console.log(process.env.MY_SECRET, process.env._MY_SECRET) // output: hello undefined
```

Why does this happen and what other options do I have to prefix my private variables?

Comment: What if you write it as `_MY_SECRET` in `.env`?

Comment: @kissu already did that in my code example

Comment: Sorry, meant `'_MY_SECRET'`, still I did not have to write it this way. Maybe depends of the version of the dotfile? Had this issue once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm, you cannot use `runtimeConfig` in a `serverMiddleware` (probably because it is out of the Nuxt context) as shown here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2033#issuecomment-773181809

I tried it myself with an underscore and it's working great with a `publicRuntimeConfig`.

---

After some research aka [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2821183/8816585) and reading the official spec, on top of some Wikipedia, it looks like `_` is a valid character for an env. Meanwhile, it is also used as a separator.

I've tried several things, found out that if you prefix it with a `_`, you won't even have it in `process.env`, this is not a dotenv issue neither (checked this one too), so I just guess that this is not possible.

##### Solution

Use `PRIVATE_MY_SECRET` and you should be good!

Comment: I don't think runtimeConfig works in serverMiddleware? In your answer you said to use process.env.PRIVATE_TOKEN directly.

Comment: `serverMiddleware` is on the server so it should totally work. And in my answer, I'm saying to use the new method. `serverMiddleware` is not a module or alike in the `nuxt.config.js`, so feel free to use the `runtimeConfig` approach @DaDo

Comment: But how do I access a runtimeConfig variable inside serverMiddleware? In a Vue component I access it via this.$config.privateToken but I do not have this context in a server.js file for example.

Comment: @DaDo oh yeah, it can also be written directly in the `nuxt.config.js` file as shown here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#usage What if you export it to some external file as shown here? https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-servermiddleware#custom-server-middleware

Comment: I don't find anything about runtimeConfig or env vars on that page. Just to be clear I already have a fully functional Express API running in my serverMiddleware and I can access variables from my .env file, just not those which start with an `_` character. Those are undefined.