# How to setup environment variables on GitHub actions for Spring Boot project

Tags: java, maven, github-actions

The Maven Clean Install step is failing on GitHub Actions because a bean requires an environment variable.

This is the bean:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:${secrets.properties}", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
public class FirebaseConfig {

    @Value("${google.credentials:invalid}")
    String googleJsonCredentials;

    @Bean("FirebaseApp")
    FirebaseApp getFirebaseApp() throws IOException {
        InputStream serviceAccount = new ByteArrayInputStream(googleJsonCredentials.getBytes());

        FirebaseOptions options = FirebaseOptions.builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://hatley-intranet.firebaseio.com").build();
        FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        return app;
    }
}
```

I want the String googleJsonCredentials to be available as an environment variable for the GitHub action:
- name: Build with Maven
run: mvn clean install

I have a secret setup in the repository called GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS:
[GitHub secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCg10.png)

I tried setting up the environment on top of the file:

```
env:
  google.credentials: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
```

I tried adding the variable to the GitHub environment as its own step:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      ...
      - name: Set Google credentials in the environment variables
        run: |
          echo "google.credentials=${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"
```

And I tried setting the variable inside the maven step:

```
      - name: Build with Maven
        env:
          google.credentials: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}
        run: mvn clean install
```

It seems the variable is setup properly:
[GitHub Action Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOqmB.png)

But none of these options worked. It can't instantiate the bean because it doesn't find the credentials.

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp]: Factory method 'getFirebaseApp' threw exception with message: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Comment: As a simple test , you declare the GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS in application.properties or yml file and try to read from there. This makes sure the possibility to read the variable value from application.properties file and so from environment variable as well.

Comment: Try setting the env var without dot e.g. `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}` and use `GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS` in the code.

Comment: Apparently, it seems related to the naming convention. See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#naming-conventions-for-configuration-variables and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821043/allowed-characters-in-linux-environment-variable-names.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved the issue:

1. My code expects to find the secrets in a file called "secrets.properties". So I set up a Maven property with name and value "secrets.properties".
2. Add the secrets to a file with that name
3. Run Maven with the -D parameter defining a system property equal to that file name

So Maven runs with that system property pointing to the file containing the secret.

YAML:

```
      - name: Set up settings.xml
        uses: s4u/maven-settings-action@v3.0.0
        with:
          properties: '[{"secrets.properties": "secrets.properties"}]'

      - name: Save secrets to file
        run: |
          echo "google_credentials=${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}" >> secrets.properties

      - name: Build with Maven
        run: mvn -Dsecrets.properties=secrets.properties clean install
```

Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "file:${secrets.properties}", ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
public class FirebaseConfig {

    @Value("${google_credentials}")
    String googleJsonCredentials;
```